# Replace multiple special character occurance with the one except

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace:

1. All consecutive special characters by its single occurrence.
2. I need to exclude `.`.

e.g.

```
$about = "   .....I......####    ";
```

should become

```
$about = " .....I......# ";
```

I wrote a regular expression:

```
$about = preg_replace("/[^\w^.]{2,}/","$1",$about);
```

but it is not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `[^\w^.]{2,}` matches any 2 or more occurrences of a char other than word, `^` and `.`.

**To match consecutive identical chars other than word and a dot**, you may use

```
([^\w.])\1+
```

and replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/92Mxgn/1).

*Details*:

- `([^\w.])` - matches and captures into Group 1 a char other than word char and a dot
- `\1+` - matches 1 or more occurrences of the value captured into Group 1.

The replacement pattern only inserts a single occurrence of the matched char.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/GRGtgo):

```
$re = '/([^\w.])\1+/';
$str = '   .....I......####    ';
$subst = '$1';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo "The result of the substitution is '".$result . "'";
```

Comment: I just encountered that `$re` in case of double quote, not working. Why is it so?

Comment: Could you please provide a live demo where this does not work? It is not possible for me to repro  because [`[^\w.]` matches a `"`](https://regex101.com/r/85FJqD/1).

Comment: Looks like I couldn't express clearly, `preg_replace("/([^\w.])\1+/","$1",$about)` not working, but `preg_replace('/([^\w.])\1+/','$1',$about)` working properly.

Comment: Sure, you forget that inside double-quoted literals, `\1` is parsed as octal number rather than a backreference to regex capture group with ID 1. You should double ``\`` before a backreference ID inside a double-quoted literal  - and in general in regexps - `preg_replace("/([^\\w.])\\1+/","$1",$about) not working, but preg_replace('/([^\w.])\1+/','$1',$about)` (remember that a literal ``\`` in both single- and double-quoted PHP string literals is represented with double ``\``, and it is more correct to write `'/([^\\w.])\\1+/'`, but it is just not necessary in a single quoted one).